# Using Job instances instead of Job classes in Quartz

Tags: class, instance, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I would like to know if it is possible to schedule a Job-Instance instead of a Job class.
I'm creating my own Job Instances and don't have the possibility to use the Job.class directly.

So something like schedule(Job job, Trigger trigger) would be great?

Comment: I know it has been a hell of long time. But can you please let me know if you found a solution for your question? I'm currently having the same problem and one step below losing my mind.

Comment: Actually i Found an ugly solution But live you said it was a longtime ago. IF i remember IT correctly There is something like a datamap Attribute where i added my Job instance and then had Access to it. I will habe a look into the old Code to bei more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. LOL your recall was solution enough actually. I ended up solving my problem by setting the Job's instance variable by passing it to the `JobDataMap` of the `JobDetail`, the same way you probably did. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I'm currently having the same problem. 
Thanks for JobDataMap solution,it's nice.
Do you find other solution?